# how to fix task :app:mergereleaseresources failed in react native release apk build

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to release apk in react native but getting this error
`task :app:mergereleaseresources failed`

If I delete the drawable and raw folder and build again then I am getting this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeBetaReleaseResources'.

Process to generate apk in react native

1. Create **keystore**
2. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`
3. `cd android`
4. `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Please help.

Comment: navigate to the android directory and then run `npx jetify` after running the following command run the above steps for generating apk.

Comment: Ok, I will check that

Comment: Duplicate Resource found error

Comment: I think your `mergeReleaseResource` issue is solved now, For the duplicate resources issue navigate to the` app/build.gradle` and check if `project.ext.react = [
   bundleInRelease: false
]` `bundleInRelease` is false. after that run `rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*

rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/raw` 

after that try to make the apk.

Comment: Removing drawable-* makes other errors happen as well, because they are not founded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigate to the android folder and run

```
npx jetify
```

this will solve your `mergereleasesource` issue.

after that, if you are facing a duplicate resource issue then run the following command

```
rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/raw
```